# Ordering in r plotly barchart

Tags: r, plotly

Why do I get the different order in plotly bar chart than I defined in x and y variables.

E.g.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)
```

I need bar chart where I see bars in the same order as x variable (categorical) is defined. Is there any trick for that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`plotly` does it in alphabetical order. If you want to change it, just try to change levels of factor. This would be possible if you give your data in the form of `data.frame` like here:

```
library(plotly)

table <- data.frame(x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
                    y = c(20, 14, 23))
table$x <- factor(table$x, levels = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"))

plot_ly(
    data=table,
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    name = "SF Zoo",
    type = "bar"
)
```

Comment: If you have a larger dataset, that is allready in the needed order you can use `table$x <- factor(table$x, levels = c(as.character(table$x)))` no need to type in every word.

Answer (score 49):

`Plotly` will order your axes by the order that is present in the data supplied. In case of `character` vectors alphabetically; in case of factors by the order of levels. To override this behaviour, you need to define `categoryorder` and `categoryarray` for the `xaxis` inside `layout`:

```
library(plotly)
xform <- list(categoryorder = "array",
              categoryarray = c("giraffes", 
                                "orangutans", 
                                "monkeys"))

plot_ly(
 x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
 y = c(20, 14, 23),
 name = "SF Zoo",
 type = "bar") %>% 
 layout(xaxis = xform)
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is more flexible than ordering based on the factors :)

Comment: saved my day! More flexible than factors for sure!

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `reorder` if you want to order based on a second variable:

```
library(plotly)
 x <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
 y <- c(20, 14, 23)

plot_ly(
  x = ~reorder(x,y),
  y = ~y,
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
  )
```