# R - plotly - cannot sort graph by value

Tags: r, plotly

I have some data that is sorted but in plotly the horizontal bar is only sorting in reverse alphabetical order but I need it to sort by a VALUE which is a number; see image 'YOY' column. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYW5x.png)

```
ecomm_yoy <- ecomm_data2019 %>%
      inner_join(ecomm_data2018, by = "Brand") %>%
      mutate(YOY = round(((Value.x - Value.y)/Value.y)*100, 2)) 

    ecomm_yoy2 <- ecomm_yoy[order(-ecomm_yoy$YOY),]

    plot_ly(x = ecomm_yoy2$YOY, y = ecomm_yoy2$Brand, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1bY4.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordering in r plotly barchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149556/ordering-in-r-plotly-barchart) ?

Comment: No because this is to order data by categories and I am trying to order by the number output as shown by YOY in the image.  I tried all the similar posts before posting the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add (using a pipe) this layout to your chart:

```
layout(yaxis = list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = ecomm_yoy2$YOY))
```

Comment: Error in UseMethod("layout") : 
  no applicable method for 'layout' applied to an object of class "list"


plot_ly(x = ecomm_yoy2$YOY, y = ecomm_yoy2$Brand, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') +
  layout(xaxis = list(categoryorder = array, categoryarray = ecomm_yoy2$YOY))

Comment: @MatthewAppleyard replace + to a pipe. I will edit my answer to be more specific.

Comment: With pipe another error! 
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: This works for me:

    data <- mtcars %>% 
      mutate(name = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
      arrange(-hp)
    
    plot_ly(data = data, x = ~hp, y= ~name, type='bar', orientation = 'h') %>%
      layout(yaxis = list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = data$name))

I still don't see how it is different than your case. :-(

Comment: @MatthewAppleyard And I forgot the quotes around array... Just edit it... Sorry

Comment: I added an layout x axis as well and it worked.  Thanks a lot for your help.  Finally it worked like this:

plot_ly(x = ecomm_yoy2$YOY, y = ecomm_yoy2$Brand, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(dtick = 5)) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = ecomm_yoy2$YOY))